# Detect length of NSMutableArray

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, nsmutablearray

I am a bit dumbstruck on how to fix this and I am not getting anywhere with my searches.

I have the following code:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
  [_testTableView beginUpdates];

  NSDictionary *dictionary = [_array00 objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.section];
  NSMutableArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];

  NSString *itemToMove = [array objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
  [array removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
  [array insertObject:itemToMove atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

  [_testTableView moveSection:fromIndexPath.section toSection:toIndexPath.section];

    //I need to know what size my array is at this point. _array00 is a NSMutableArray made up from 2 other NSMutableArrays.

  [_testTableView endUpdates];
```

}

So I am making an app that allows you to re-order the `cells` from one `group` to another in a `UITableViewController`.

I am not sure if I am going to word this right, but I hope it makes sense.

I need to check on runtime when the size of the `NSMutableArray` changes because I moving a `row` from one `section` to another.
Can somebody please help me out :-)

Comment: When are items added or removed to the mutable array?  Don't you control that?  Can you update your table when the items are changed?

Comment: Yes, what @AaronBrager means is, how can you _not_ know, since _you_ are the one making the changes.

Comment: mmm ok - it is not that I don't know, I am more meaning what to do in terms of the Controller to understand it and then I was wondering if it is in the right place in terms of flow of the app. - I will update the comment :-)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to add itemToMove to same section.. Add the itemToMove to the toindexpath.section array..

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView moveRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)fromIndexPath toIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)toIndexPath
{
[_testTableView beginUpdates];

NSDictionary *dictionary = [_array00 objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.section];
NSMutableArray *array = [dictionary objectForKey:@"data"];

NSString *itemToMove = [array objectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];
  [array removeObjectAtIndex:fromIndexPath.row];

NSDictionary *toDictionary = [_array00 objectAtIndex:toIndexPath.section];
NSMutableArray *toArray = [toDictionary objectForKey:@"data"];
  [toArray insertObject:itemToMove atIndex:toIndexPath.row];

[_testTableView moveSection:fromIndexPath.section toSection:toIndexPath.section];

//This is where I assume my missing code has to go

  [_testTableView endUpdates];
}
```

I hope this may fix your issue..

Comment: I am using a grouped layout, so there are 2 sections - the answer you gave is still crashing, but was trying to work out why.